# In practice, is it safe to set Strict-Transport-Security header on non-SSL requests?

Tags: http

Section 7.2 of [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797) states:

> An HSTS Host MUST NOT include the STS header field in HTTP responses
> conveyed over non-secure transport.

In practice, I have a lot of hosts that are behind an Amazon load balancer that where requests from ports 443 and 80 are forwarded to the same Nginx configuration.  It would be considerably simpler to always send the `Strict-Transport-Security` header, regardless of the incoming protocol used.

I don't care if the UA ignores the header on insecure requests. I'd just to like to confirm if this RFC violation causes a problem in practice.

Insecure requests are already redirected to secure versions by the server, where the UA would then receive a valid `Secure-Transport-Security` header in their response.

Comment: Clarification: You want to send the header back on all requests?

Comment: I have never seen or heard of anywhere it causes a problem in practice, to this point.   I know there was at least one very large site that has, at least in the past, intentionally sent HTST headers on HTTP requests, seemingly without issue.  As chexum points on in his answer, because of the MUST NOT, this will not necessarily always be the case.

Comment: (After migration) Dupe of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84714/why-does-rfc6797-say-an-hsts-host-must-not-include-the-sts-header-field-in-http which answers that 8.1 says client MUST ignore HSTS on HTTP. Also http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103507/hsts-on-sites-available-over-http-and-https

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the requirement is `MUST NOT`, then in theory some browser can display an error instead of a page that has this header when fetched via plain HTTP.  It is highly unlikely though.

(Update: this unlikely behaviour is actually forbidden by the same RFC.)

Clearly the point is that over HTTP nothing can be trusted to originate from the original server, so if any browser would interpret it when seen with HTTP, then this header could be (ab)used to force the server appear offline for an extended time without the consent of the server operator, with sufficient capabilities to control the network path.

New UA/client software authors still could make a mistake of interpreting this header, and it can be a good protection against this if you make it a requirement to not ever issue HSTS via HTTP - so that it can be flagged and reported as an error by any validator.

Though I did not test this, with nginx, it's not very complicated to say:

```
if ($scheme = https) {
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=18000000;
}
```

The only issue I can foresee is when you have a limited SSL offloading frontend proxy and you can't easily tell whether the request is SSL or not.  In that case you actually must issue HSTS via HTTP, assuming your CDN/proxy does not have a way to configure HSTS.

Comment: For Amazon's load balancer see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-proto

Comment: @JohnMorahan, I do use "X-Forwarded-Proto" to check the original protocol, but I want to avoid the "if" suggested by chexum because of the [official recommendation not not use Nginx "if" like that](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: @MarkStosberg - the warning appears to apply for the location context only.  Unless your nginx is serving multiple frontend domains proxied to subpaths, the server context is just fine for the `add_header`, conditional or not.

Comment: @chexum I found that despite the "If is Evil" article, there are some directives that are explicitly supported in the "if in location" context, and `add_header` is from them. Check the official docs for the [supported contexts of add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

While the `if` directive can be used to limit the HSTS header to HTTPS, it becomes messy when you have multiple `location` blocks in your virtual host file. I came across the following solution in an Nginx [trac ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/289).

```
map $scheme $hsts_header {
    https   max-age=31536000;
}

server {
    listen  80;
    listen  443 ssl;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security $hsts_header;
}
```